# Добавление фото профиля в базу данных на Flask

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask

Есть форма регистрации. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно добавить фото профиля в базу данных и сразу же получить его обратно. Знаю что можно как-то с помощью `AJAX`, но не знаю как это реализовать. При регистрации в базу добавляется только имя картинки, и я не могу ее получить на странице `profile`. В чем может быть проблема?

`Код Регистрации:`

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.form['firstname']
        lastname = request.form['lastname']
        email = request.form['email']
        filenames = request.files['files']

    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")
    filenames = []
    for file in uploaded_files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
            filenames.append(filename)
    # This line is essential, store the data in session
    session['filenames'] = filenames

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        session['email'] = email
        session['firstname'] = firstname
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO users.data(firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', (firstname, lastname, email))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
```

`profile.html:`

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('profile.html', data=data, filenames=filenames)
```

`register.html:`

```
<input type="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
<input type="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="First name">
<input type='file' name="files" id="uploadPDF">
<button>Register</button>
```

`profile.html:`

```
<h2>Welcome, {{ firstname }}</h2>

{% for file in filenames %}
  <h1>{{ file }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Теория и примеры](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/zagruzka-failov)

[Пример 2](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

[Пример 3](https://wp-kama.ru/id_9026/jquery-ajax-zagruzka-fajlov-na-server.html)
После прочтения думаю вопросы отпадут. Но все же вы должны понимать что все фото будут храниться у вас на сервере. Следующий вопрос как их именовать ?
Как по мне есть два варика:
Первый например именовать фото в id пользователя, тобиж 20.jpg 21.jpg ...
Второй именовать КАК угодно, но в бд сделать столбец где будет указано имя фото для каждого юзера.
Вот как то так =)

Comment: я использую фреймворк `Flask`, пишу на питоне

Comment: обновил код. Можете посмотреть пожалуйста?

Comment: @abby Вроде бы все хорошо)

Comment: да вот не работает что-то

Comment: @abby Что именно не работает ? Не выводиться информация тут ```{% for file in filenames %}
  <h1>{{ file }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
``` Или страница полностью пустая ?

Comment: да, ничего не выводится. Мне кажется я что-то упускаю(

Comment: @abby Почему у вас profile.html содержит код python ?) и попробуйте выводить значения так ```{{ user.username }}!``` Согласно этой статье на хабре: https://habr.com/ru/post/346340/